# Prove that $\frac1{a+b+1}+\frac1{b+c+1}+\frac1{c+a+1}\le1$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, fractions, substitution, muirhead-inequality

If $abc=1$ then

$$\frac1{a+b+1}+\frac1{b+c+1}+\frac1{c+a+1}\le1$$

I have tried AM-GM and C-S and can't seem to find a solution. What is the best way to prove it?

Comment: Have u tried using the transformation a=x/y ,b=y/z and c=z/x then use partial differentiation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also we can use the following reasoning.

For positives $a$, $b$ and $c$ let $a=x^3$, $b=y^3$ and $c=z^3$.

Hence, $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{a+b+1}=\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{x^3+y^3+xyz}\leq\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{x^2y+y^2x+xyz}=\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{z}{x+y+z}=1$,

but I think the first way is better.

Comment: Thanks, great tricks. Just a typo, $x^3+y^3\ge x^2y+y^2x$

Comment: @Weiqing Wu Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It's wrong, of course.

For positives $a$, $b$ and $c$ it's $\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c-2a)\geq0$, which is Muirhead because $(2,1,0)\succ\left(\frac{5}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3}\right)$.

Comment: Could you explain a little more explicitly how Muirhead applies here? I've rarely seen the inequality used before (not counting applications of AM-GM) and would love to see the application.

Comment: @Michael Lee $\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(a^2b+a^2c-2a\right)=\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(a^2b+a^2c-2a^{\frac{5}{3}}b^{\frac{2}{3}}c^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)\geq0$, by Muirhead.

Comment: Ahh, I see now. Clever!